# Creating Tables with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm getting an error when I'm loading the DataTable. I dont see anything wrong. My table is right and I'm loading the DataTable() after i create the table. Note that I dont get any error when I change the dropbox and reload the table

The error is here: `$('#dataTable').dataTable();`

**What's the problem?? I need to fix it because this causes the Datable script not to work.**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined
>       at HTMLTableCellElement. (jquery.dataTables.js:1197)
>       at Function.each (jquery-1.9.1.js:648)
>       at init.each (jquery-1.9.1.js:270)
>       at HTMLTableElement. (jquery.dataTables.js:1194)
>       at Function.each (jquery-1.9.1.js:648)
>       at init.each (jquery-1.9.1.js:270)
>       at init.DataTable [as dataTable] (jquery.dataTables.js:869)
>       at HTMLDocument. (accounts.js:172)
>       at fire (jquery-1.9.1.js:1037)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.9.1.js:1148)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var types = [];
    var amountOfDayEnds = parseInt($('#amountOfDayEnds').val());

    function DisplayTable() {
        var data;
        //Table
        $('.dataTableBody').empty();
        for(var i=1;i<=amountOfDayEnds;i++) {
            data += '<tr align="center">';
            data += '<td>' + i + '</td>';
            $.each(types, function (index, value) {
                data += '<td>' + '<input class="text-center amountOfAccounts" type="number" value="0" name="amountOfAccounts-' + value + '"  data-error="Please, insert a value"  required>' + '</td>'
            });
            data += '</tr>';
        }
        $('.dataTableBody').append(data);
    }


//Repeat the value for all rows in Clients Table
    $('.repeatForAll').change(function () {
        var number = $('.repeatForAll').val();
        $('.amountOfClients').val(number);
    });

 


    //create the interdepent selectors
    function initSelectors(){
        // next 2 statements should generate error message, see console
        MAIN.createRelatedSelector();
        MAIN.createRelatedSelector(document.querySelector('#cls') );

        //countries
        MAIN.createRelatedSelector
        ( document.querySelector('#cls')           // from select element
            ,document.querySelector('#group')      // to select element
            ,{                                               // values object
                Deposit: ['DDA','SAV'],
                Loan: ['MTG'],
            }
            ,function(a,b){return a>b ? 1 : a<b ? -1 : 0;}   // sort method
        );
    }

//create MAIN namespace
    (function(ns){ // don't pollute the global namespace

        function create(from, to, obj, srt){
            if (!from) {
                throw CreationError('create: parameter selector [from] missing');
            }
            if (!to) {
                throw CreationError('create: parameter related selector [to] missing');
            }
            if (!obj) {
                throw CreationError('create: related filter definition object [obj] missing');
            }

            //retrieve all options from obj and add it
            obj.all = (function(o){
                var a = [];
                for (var l in o) {
                    a = /array/i.test (o[l].constructor) ? a.concat(o[l]) : a;
                }
                return a.sort(srt);
            }(obj));
            // initialize and populate to-selector with all
            populator.call( from
                ,null
                ,to
                ,obj
                ,srt
            );

            // assign handler
            from.onchange = populator;

            function initStatics(fn,obj){
                for (var l in obj) {
                    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(l)){
                        fn[l] = obj[l];
                    }
                }
                fn.initialized = true;
            }

            function populator(e, relatedto, obj, srt){
                // set pseudo statics
                var self = populator;
                if (!self.initialized) {
                    initStatics(self,{optselects:obj,optselectsall:obj.all,relatedTo:relatedto,sorter:srt || false});
                }

                if (!self.relatedTo){
                    throw 'not related to a selector';
                }
                // populate to-selector from filter/all
                var optsfilter = this.selectedIndex < 1
                    ? self.optselectsall
                    : self.optselects[this.options[this.selectedIndex].firstChild.nodeValue]
                    ,cselect = self.relatedTo
                    ,opts = cselect.options;
                if (self.sorter) optsfilter.sort(self.sorter);
                opts.length = 0;
                for (var i=0;i<optsfilter.length;i+=1){
                    opts[i] = new Option(optsfilter[i],optsfilter[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        // custom Error
        function CreationError(mssg){
            return {name:'CreationError',message:mssg};
        }

        // return the create method with some error handling
        window[ns] = {
            createRelatedSelector: function(from,to,obj,srt) {
                try {
                    if (arguments.length<1) {
                        throw CreationError('no parameters');
                    }
                    create.call(null,from,to,obj,srt);
                }
                catch(e) { console.log('createRelatedSelector ->',e.name,'\n'
                    + e.message +
                    '\ncheck parameters'); }
            }
        };
    }('MAIN'));

    //initialize
    initSelectors();

    //get account types based on group
    $('#group').change(TypesChanged);
    $('#cls').change(TypesChanged);

    function TypesChanged() {
        selectedGroup = $('#group').val();
        switch (selectedGroup) {
            case "DDA":
                types = ["400","4044","4045"];
                break;
            case "SAV":
                types = ["300","310"];
                break;
            case "MTG":
                types = ["700","710"];
                break;
        }
        console.log("Selected group: " + selectedGroup + ", Types: " + types);
        $('.dataTableHead').empty();
        $('.dataTableFooter').empty();
        $('.dataTableHead').append('<th class="text-center">Day</th>');
        $('.dataTableFooter').append('<th class="text-center">Day</th>');
        var columnNames = [];
        $.each(types, function (index, value) {
            columnNames += '<th class="text-center">Type ' + value + '</th>';
        });
        $('.dataTableHead').append(columnNames);
        $('.dataTableFooter').append(columnNames);
        DisplayTable();
    }

    TypesChanged();
    $('#dataTable').dataTable();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Page level plugin JavaScript-->
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


                <div class="row text-right">
                        <label>
                            Show
                            <select name="cls" id="cls">
                                <option value="All">All</option>
                                <option value="Deposit">Deposit</option>
                                <option value="Loan">Loan</option>
                            </select>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label>
                            Show
                            <select name="group" id="group">
                                <%--Jquery--%>
                            </select>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                            <thead class="dataTableHead">
                            <tr>
                              
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tfoot class="dataTableFooter">
                            <tr>
                                
                            </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                            <tbody class="dataTableBody">
                            
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Comment: "Whats the problem" -> You have pasted the problem, yet you still ask?
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined` is the problem. Or in other words, the variable `mData` is not defined on the page anywhere... where is that variable in your code?

Comment: that variable is from the DataTable script. https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html   . It has an error because of my code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: `$('#amountOfDayEnds')` is referring to nowhere, element is missing on the page, so body is not being generated at all, there are no rows, nothing to fill.

Found the problem, the table is missing table row in header and footer after .empty call

add tr  in function TypesChanged() in next selectors:
from:

`$('.dataTableHead').empty();
 $('.dataTableFooter').empty();
 $('.dataTableHead').append('<th class="text-center">Day</th>');
 $('.dataTableFooter').append('<th class="text-center">Day</th>');`

`$('.dataTableHead').append(columnNames);
$('.dataTableFooter').append(columnNames);`

to:

`$('.dataTableHead tr').empty();
$('.dataTableFooter tr').empty();
$('.dataTableHead tr').append('<th class="text-center">Day</th>');
$('.dataTableFooter tr').append('<th class="text-center">Day</th>');`

`$('.dataTableHead tr').append(columnNames);
$('.dataTableFooter tr').append(columnNames);`

Comment: it's there. it's not that. I have a hidden input above. I forgot to put it there. The table is correctly displayed but I cant apply DataTable()